# What to do to mix coffescript and typescript files in the same nodejs project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, typescript, package.json

In a server side node project with the standard package.json, How should we mix coffescript and typescript files?

The `npm install`, `npm test` and `npm start` **functionality** should still be available. The commands themselves are not essencial.

Extra info:

- the coffeescript and Typescript need to be able to talk to each other as much as possible
- the project is written in [Expres](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express)

Comment: Is using a single higher order language an option? Why mix two together? That sounds like a recipe for maintenance issues. Does the CoffeeSciprt and TypeScript files need to communicate with each other or are they completely separate? Is this for client code or a node server?

Comment: Hi. This might be a recipy for disaster but it might also be a way for people to actually understand which one to choose before the project gets too big?

Comment: @arb It is for server code.

Comment: @arb I believe I answered your other doubts . Let me know if you think anything else is unclear.

Comment: I only know TypeScript; but I know that Typescript allows you to define `.d.ts` files to fill in the type-information blanks for any modules written in CoffeeScript. That still leaves the other half though; if it's not a language of firm dependencies, then that might be all you need, but I think someone else would have to confirm the rest.

Comment: Anyone knows why the ''-1"? Without any feedback, it is hard for me to know how to improve the question!

Answer (score 1):

> How should we mix coffescript and typescript files?

Just add `node.d.ts` and then you should be able to just `var/require` coffescript files from typescript just fine. To require typescript files compile them to JS (using an IDE like atom, or grunt / gulp packages) and then you should be able to require them just fine.

To use TypeScript from typescript use `import/require` (instead of `var/require`) and then compile with `--module commonjs`.

Comment: Pretty soon I will have Labdays. So I will be able to try this out and see where it takes me.

Have you actually tried this and can you ngive me more details please?

Comment: Atom-TypeScript has coffeescript as well as TypeScript files : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript

Comment: It will take me a while try and tackle this problem at work. But if I forget for too long to accept your answer or give a better one, please remind me. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexandreMartins did you figure this out? Can you post your own answer or accept this one?

Comment: @DheerajBhaskar We ended up not doing the switch so I never got to try the approach mentioned here. If you try it, just paste an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: Or. if @basarat 's answer works for you, I can mark it as well.